# Golang can't ExecuteTemplate

Tags: templates, go

I need to `ExecuteTemplate` (text and html). I have next snippet:

```
import ("text/template")
...

test_path := "/cnaize/home/test.txt"
testTmpl := template.New(test_path)
var test bytes.Buffer
if err := testTmpl.ExecuteTemplate(&test, test_path, mm.Args); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

but I have error `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` in `ExecuteTemplate`. When I change first line to `import ("html/template")`, I have `"/cnaize/home/test.txt" is an incomplete template` error.
My `test.txt`:

```
Test
```

Where may be a problem?

**EDITED:**
I know about documentation, but I found this solution in https://github.com/arkxu/gomail/blob/master/message.go and it's exactly what I need, because I don't know how to set `args` in `template.ParseFiles()`. `template.New()` with folder name is ok. And my `mm.Args` is `map[message:Hello there!]`, I've checked it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things wrong here:

1. `template.New()` initializes an empty template with the given name, you are giving a path, which is ok, but it probably is not what you want. Please read the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) before using libraries naively.
   You are probably looking for: [template.ParseFiles()](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles)
2. what is `mm.Args`? From that snippet alone and the error I would guess `mm` is nil.

Comment: It is not what you need. That's why you receive the incomplete template error. Your template is empty when you use `template.New("whatever")`. Please read the doc. It also seems like you are still confused about how the template package works. You pass the args on executing templates and it has nothing to do with `template.ParseFiles()`.